# Receive data from api. python, requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape data from URL1 = https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B&sort=popular

Found out API of this site URL2= https://nm-2-card.wildberries.ru/enrichment/v1/api?spp=0&regions=69,63,66,31,48,22,30,4,1,68,70,64,40,38,71,33,65&stores=116433,115577,117501,507,3158,2737,1699,1733,686,117986,6158,117673,119261,117413&couponsGeo=3,12,15,18&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=0&appType=1&offlineBonus=0&onlineBonus=0&emp=0&nm=7403217;7403219;7777517;7777518;9132344;9132356;9132362;9254700;9254707;9254711;9361310;9361312;9642551;9929901;10129965;10140147;10140149;10140156;10210357;10555010;10557917;10557928;10557931;10848573;10848575;10848583;11190841;11477541;11550153;11632388;11665068;11712962;11712963;11712964;11712965;11712966;11734372;11734374;11764432;11989953;12060487;12200001;12200004;12200005;12206097;12237827;12242309;12383696;12383697;12383702;12383711;12554112;12554119;12554124;12554127;12554128;12554129;12554130;12554164;12554166;12554167;12609241;12620265;13238159;13238160

How can I make request to URL1 and receive data from URL2 ?

**code**

```
import requests

url1 = "https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B&sort=popular"
response = requests.get(url1)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if there's an API with structured data like this, use that url to get the data you want. Sometimes you might have to re-engineer the HTTP request by adding in headers, cookies and parameters. This one was very simple to get you didn't need any of that.

The json() method will give you a dictionary. So you'll have to go through the dictionary to get the desired data. You haven't told us which data it is so this is as much help as I can give you.

### Code Example

```
import requests
html = requests.get('https://nm-2-card.wildberries.ru/enrichment/v1/api?spp=0&regions=69,63,66,31,48,22,30,4,1,68,70,64,40,38,71,33,65&stores=116433,115577,117501,507,3158,2737,1699,1733,686,117986,6158,117673,119261,117413&couponsGeo=3,12,15,18&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=0&appType=1&offlineBonus=0&onlineBonus=0&emp=0&nm=7403217;7403219;7777517;7777518;9132344;9132356;9132362;9254700;9254707;9254711;9361310;9361312;9642551;9929901;10129965;10140147;10140149;10140156;10210357;10555010;10557917;10557928;10557931;10848573;10848575;10848583;11190841;11477541;11550153;11632388;11665068;11712962;11712963;11712964;11712965;11712966;11734372;11734374;11764432;11989953;12060487;12200001;12200004;12200005;12206097;12237827;12242309;12383696;12383697;12383702;12383711;12554112;12554119;12554124;12554127;12554128;12554129;12554130;12554164;12554166;12554167;12609241;12620265;13238159;13238160')
data = html.json()
```

### Example Output

```
{'state': 0,
 'data': {'products': [{'id': 7403217,
    'root': 5797737,
    'kindId': 0,
    'subjectId': 3111,
    'name': 'Макароны звездочки',
    'brand': 'Гурмайор',
    'brandId': 27327,
    'siteBrandId': 37327,
    'price': 542,
    'sale': 34,
    'salePrice': 355,
    'extended': {'basicSale': 20,
     'basicPrice': 433,
     'promoSale': 18,
     'promoPrice': 355},
    'picsCount': 1,
    'rating': 3,
    'feedbackCount': 6,
    'isAdult': False,
    'isDigital': False,
    'icons': {'isNew': False},
    'colors': [],
    'sizes': [{'name': '',
      'origName': '0',
      'rank': 0,
      'optionId': 25559509,
      'stocks': [{'wh': 507, 'qty': 103}]}],
    'diffPrice': False},
```

### Code Example using Selenium

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'c:\users\aaron\chromedriver.exe')
url ='https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B&sort=popular'
driver.get(url)
card = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="dtList i-dtList j-card-item "]')

for a in card: 
     food = a.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="goods-name c-text-sm"]').text
     try:
        lower_price = a.find_element_by_xpath('.//ins[@class="lower-price"]').text
     except NoSuchElementException:
        lower_price = 'No reduction'
     try: 
        full_price = a.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="price-old-block"]/del').text
    
     except NoSuchElementException:
        full_price = 'No price'
```

### Explanation

Selenium works by a webdriver module which allows you to automate browser testing. It's a framework that is primarily for testing and not necessarily for webscraping but the community of web scrapers have used it because its one of few ways to handle javascript heavy websites.

Selenium provides drivers for specific browsers. The browser driver interacts with the respective browser via a secure connection. These browser drivers are specific to the language used for the automation.

So the following tasks occur when you want to mimic browser activity.

1. An HTTP request is generated and delivered to the browser driver
2. This request is received by the driver through an HTTP server
3. All steps executed on the browser is decided by the HTTP server

[Here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-webdriver-tutorial#:%7E:text=Selenium%20WebDriver%20is%20a%20web,choice%20to%20create%20test%20scripts.) is a relatively good write up on the overview.

So we import the webdriver module and this allows us to do browser activity. We have to have chromedriver which how we do browser activity. You can get it from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).

We have to stipulate where that chromedriver is on our drive. Which I've done here. We're using chrome and we specify via the `executable_path` keyword argument.

We use the get method and specify the url we want the browser to load.

Now that the browser has loaded the page we can access all the page. We do this via the find_elements_by methods. There's quite a few different ones to choose from. Here we've chosen `find_elements_by_xpath()` method. We specify an XPATH selector and it allows us to extract the data we want. Note find_elements_by_xpath grabs ALL elements with the XPATH selector and puts them into a list. If there's only one element use `find_element_by_xpath()` method.

Because the card variable is a list, we can do a for loop to further extract data from that part of the website. In this case we have selected each 'CARD' on the website which contents information about each item of food. You can check the class with the HTML of the website if you like. By using `find_elements_by_xpath` we are selecting all the items of food 'cards' on the website. We can then further extract information within those divs, using `find_element_by_xpath`.

Basics of XPATH selectors

- `//`: Searches the entire website
- `div`: search for a div tag
- `[@class=""]`: specifies the class of the preceding tag

Selenium:

- `.text`: this grabs the text of that html tag

So the line of code `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="dtList i-dtList j-card-item "]')`

Searches throught the entire HTML document, looks for div's with a class `'tList i-dtList j-card-item '` and selects it. With that we can extract data from all the html tags within that div.

We then do a for loop on the list. With find_element_by_xpath we are look for one element only. The `.//` searches within the parent div. So here we search for the span with the class. The `.text` selects the text of that tag.

We use a try except block, with NoSuchElementException. This is used for when there are items that don't have a price which would through a NoSuchElement Exception, so we can take that exception and we can then input a string of our chosing.

Without more information that's a primer on selenium for doing this. I suggest you give it a go and use the selenium docs to get your head round it.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to extract URL2. At the start i know only URL1

Comment: How can I do It?

Comment: You will need to use the package selenium to automate browser activity. All the data on this page is through javascript. If you turn off javascript in your browser you will not see anything of use (you can try this and other websites if you're unsure). Generally speaking if that's the case there are two options. Reverese Engineering the HTTP requests, which is what my answer does or you have to simulate browser activity. The probably with simulating browser activity is that it is brittle and generally slower

Comment: You also havent expanded on what data you actually want... there's only so much I can help you.

Comment: I've provided a coding example with selenium but if you've never used selenium you have some reading to do! I'll do my best to explain it.

Comment: I know  selenium. But is there solution with help of requests or scrapy?

Comment: As I said before. This website relies heavily on javascript. I have already explained to you and provided two ways to do work round the fact it heavily relies on javascript. You could use the reverse engineering the HTTP requests with scrapy. It also has some support for javascript via splash and 3rd party library called scrapy-selenium you can look those up if you like. There is no possibiliy of using requests, it has no support for javascript.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful if you explain what you are trying to achieve with grabbing this data. Because that will dictate the frameworks used to do the web scrape. Reverse engineering the HTTP request is the most robust and reliaable way of getting the data you want. You could use that in scrapy if you like

Comment: I should say, the only way you can use URL1 to grab the data you want is to use selenium or use scrapy-selenium/scrapy-splash.